# Can custom lightning components be added to standard page layouts

Tags: lightning-aura-components, page-layout

I would like to be able to create a record using the standard page layout, but I would like to also allow the addition of a custom component to that page layout.

Currently , it seems that the only way to get custom components is to create a completely new component and code in the individual fields into that component. I don't like this solution because it makes it difficult to maintain.

However, if I wanted to require information from my custom component, I have no way of doing that with a standard creation/edit page layout.

Is it possible to add a custom component to a page layout, or even add a page layout to a custom component so I don't have to hard code the fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [force:recordView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordView.htm) to place an entire record view (dictated by page layout) in to a custom component. Requires SLDS to view properly, and links/hovers only work in LEX. You can also use [force:recordEdit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordEdit.htm) if you want to be able to create/edit a record, instead.

Comment: Does force:recordEdit work without an id, though? Wouldn't {!v.myObject.recordId} return null and then error out?

Comment: Yes, looks like it expects either record or recordId. So this wouldn't work for new records, but should meet your requirements for viewing existing records no?

Comment: @Chance Yeah, I just realized that, too. But technically, creating a new record does not use the record page, but instead uses a modal dialog, which you'd fire off with force:createRecord instead.

Comment: @sfdcfox so if that uses a modal box, is there any way to insert my own custom component into that modal so that I can require information from that before the record can be saved? It seems as though I am still in the same position. Is there a way to redirect after the record save to my component.

Comment: @Chance Nope. Say, any reason why you're not just making a Lightning Record Page? That way, you can show your custom component as well as the record details...

Comment: @sfdcfox the custom component is a lookup through junction objects. To illustrate, it will have a lookup to contact and then have a picklist that is filtered to only include Accounts related to the selected contact. That account is then stored on the original record. I'd like to require that account field before saving/creating, and I can't seem to figure out a way to do that.